# Clear Filter button for table not wotking

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am using datatables for my project and I am filtering the columns using dropdown menu on top. Everything works fine. However, I am not sure why Clear filter button is not working. I am sure it is something simple that I am missing but I cannot figure it out. Without Reset Filter working, the table doesn't seem user friendly.

Here is link to my code - https://live.datatables.net/mijecofu/1/edit
Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
responsive: true,
searching: true
});
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
table.columns(0).search( this.value ).draw();
} );
$('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
} );
$('#dropdown3').on('change', function () {
table.columns(2).search( this.value ).draw();
});


 buildSelect(table);
 
  table.on('draw', function() {
    buildSelect(table);
  });
  $('#test').on('click', function() {
    table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
<div class="searchbox">
<p>Name: <select id="dropdown1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>Ashton Cox</option>
<option>Brielle Williamson</option>
<option>Cedric Kelly</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Postion: <select id="dropdown2">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>Technical Author</option>
<option>Integration Specialist</option>
<option>Javascript Developer</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>Office: <select id="dropdown3">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>San Francisco</option>
<option>New York</option>
  <option>Edinburgh</option>
</select>
</p>
  <button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>
</div>
  <table id="example" class="cell-border row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;"><thead>
<tr>

<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th>&#160;</th>
<th colspan="3" style=" text-align: center;">Information</th>
</tr>


          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors?

Comment: It works now. Someone rectified my code. nit sure why I cannot see that anymore